# How does the kernel initialize and access the rest of the hardware on x86/64?

Tags: operating-system, driver, hardware, bios, uefi

I'm interested in the details of how operating systems work and perhaps writing my own.

From what I've gathered, the BIOS/UEFI is supposed to handle setting up the hardware, and do things like memory-mapping (or IO ports for) the graphics card and other IO devices like audio and ethernet.

My question is, how does the kernel know how to access and (re)configure these devices when it's passed control from the bootloader? Are there just conventions like 'the graphics card is always memory mapped from X to Y address space'? Are you at the mercy of a hardware manufacturer writing a driver for an operating system which knows how the hardware will be initialized?

That seems wrong, so maybe the kernel code includes instructions which somehow iterate through all the bus-connected devices. But what instructions can accomplish that? Is the PCI(e) controller also a memory-mapped device? How do you begin querying and setting up the system?

My primary reference has been the Intel 64 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, which has excellent documentation on how the CPU works, but doesn't describe how the system is setup.

Answer (score 0):

I never wrote a firmware so I don't really know how that works in general. You probably have some memory detection done like an actual memory iteration that is done and some interrogation of PCI devices that are memory mapped in RAM. You also probably have some information in the Developer's manuals as to how you should get some information about memory and stuff like that.

In the end, the kernel doesn't need to bother about that because the firmware takes care to do all that and to provide temporary drivers before the kernel is set up completely.

The firmware passes information to the kernel using the ACPI tables so that is the convention you are looking for. The UEFI  firmware launches the /efi/boot/bootx64.efi EFI app from the hard-disk automatically. It calls the main function of that app often called the bootloader. When you write that application, often with frameworks such as EDK2 or GNU-EFI, you can thus use the temporary drivers to get some information like the location of the RSDP which points to all other ACPI tables.

The ACPI convention specifies a language that is AML which, when your kernel interprets, tells it all about hardware. You thus have all the required information there to load drivers and such.

PCI (which is everything nowadays) is another thing. It works with memory mapped IO but the ACPI tables (the MCFG) is helpful to find the beginning of the configuration space for PCI devices that take the form of memory mapped registers.

As to graphics cards, you probably don't want to start with those. They are complex and, at first, you should probably stick to the framebuffer returned by UEFI and at least write a driver for xHCI which is the PCI host controller responsible to interact with USB including keyboards and mouses.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! Especially the part about the ACPI; I'll look into that